Waypoints Animation Scroll
I'm trying to mimic a feature like on this site: https://maggiefornh.com/
As you scroll the page the content fades and animates in. It looks like they are using waypoint.js. Here is my code:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: $('#waypoint'),
        handler: function(direction) {
          $('#waypoint').toggleClass('active', direction === 'down');
        },
        offset: '50%'
      });
    });
  </script>


And what is your question? Where are you stuck? What is not working? [ask]
